# What is the idea of having colon between datatype and value in cpp?

Tags: c++, syntax

I can understand the purpose of having a colon after constructor in Cpp. ([What is this weird colon-member (" : ") syntax in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)).
But what is the purpose of the format, **datatype colon value** as following

```
unsigned AttrKind : 8;
```

I found this in private variables of a class. I have only a basic idea of Cpp and its not digesting for me.

If I am not wrong, its not a bit field as this variable is not declared inside a structure. its in the private section of a class

Comment: It's a [bit field](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field). `AttrKind` is to only take up 8 bits. Dunno why they didn't just use [`uint8_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

Comment: See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field

Comment: It's not a bitstream. The thing is its just in the private section of a class and is not part of any structure

Comment: @GinuJacob: In C++, both `struct` and `class` declare compound objects; either can include bit fields. The only difference between `struct` and `class` is the default visibility.